# How to substitute values in matrix operation without solving?

Tags: python, matrix, printing, sympy

Literally what it says in the title. Let's pretend the operation is addition of matrices.

```
from sympy import Matrix, latex
A = Matrix([[-7, 0], [4, 0]]) 
B = Matrix([[2, 0], [-3, -3]])

print( (A+B).a_method_that_evaluates_but_does_not_solve() )
```

I would like to get the following output.

```
[[-7 + 2, 0 + 0], [4 - 3, 0 - 3]]
```

I will use this with various matrix operations, including addition, multiplication and scalar multiplication. And my goal is to be able to print the working as one or more of this operations is performed. Ultimately, having the control to decide when to substitute only, and when to solve.

So far, the closest I have gotten is to print the symbolic working. Here is the 2x2 matrix example. But this is not good, I really want the actual numbers printed. And using the `subs` method, substitutes AND solves the operations. Which is the same as `print(A+B)`.

```
symA = MatrixSymbol('A', 2, 2)
symB = MatrixSymbol('B', 2, 2)
print(Matrix(symA+symB))
print((symA+symB).subs(symA,A).subs(symB,B))
```

With output:

```
Matrix([[A[0, 0] + B[0, 0], A[0, 1] + B[0, 1]], [A[1, 0] + B[1, 0], A[1, 1] + B[1, 1]]])
Matrix([[-5, 0], [1, -3]])
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using an `evaluate(False)` context if you do the operations manually within the context (and I don't know why it doesn't work for simply adding the matrices):

```py
A = Matrix([[-7, 0], [4, 0]]) 
B = Matrix([[2, 0], [-3, -3]])
with evaluate(False):
    C = Matrix(2,2, [i+j for i,j in zip(A,B)])
    D = Matrix([[sum([A[i,k]*B[k,j] for k in range(2)]) for j in range(2)] for i in range(2)])

>>> C
Matrix([
[-7 + 2, 0 + 0], 
[-3 + 4, -3 + 0]])
>>> C.doit()
Matrix([
[-5, 0], 
[1, -3]])
>>> D
Matrix([
[-(7*2 + 0) + 0*(-3), (0 - 7*0) + 0*(-3)], 
[0*(-3) + (0 + 4*2), (0 + 4*0) + 0*(-3)]])
>>> D.doit() == A*B
True
```

You can always write helpers if you think that would be more convenient:

```py
def add(A, B):
    assert A.shape == B.shape
    with evaluate(False):
        return Matrix(*A.shape, [i+j for i,j in zip(A,B)])

def mul(A, B):
    assert A.cols == B.rows
    with evaluate(False):
        rv =Matrix([[sum([A[i,k]*B[k,j] for k in range(A.cols)]) for j in range(B.cols)] for i in range(A.rows)])
        return rv.replace(lambda x:x.is_Add and x.args[0] == 0,
                          lambda x: Add(*x.args[1:], evaluate=False)) 

>>> add(A,B).doit() == A+B and mul(A,B).doit() == A*B
True
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. Except, as you say, that it does't work for sympy matrix operations.

Comment: It would be beautiful if I could just write `C = A + B` or `C = A * B`. If someone finds out how to make it work, or if it is possible, I'll mark that as the correct answer.

Comment: Hey, I just noticed that it does not work literally as intended. For some reason, while evaluating, the order in which the operations is performed changes. For example, if the first matrix had a 7 and the second matrix had a 0 in the same coordinate. The addition would display `0+7` instead of `7+0`. Is there a way to prevent that from happening too?

Comment: With multiplication is a bit worse, since the `sum` works as a reduce operation with starting value of `0`. The starting value is always printed!

Comment: The mul routine has been updated to remove the 0 in a sum (but not the product of 0 and a number).

Comment: The order that the printer prints the elements is not under control of the `evaluate` flag.